# Reputation and Privileges

Tags: bug, privileges, help-center

In the side bar of the site when looking at the Help Centre there are two areas for Privileges.

One is listed with Reputation but has nothing to do with Privileges only Reputation. And the other Privileges that has all the information about it.

[image]

Comment: is it a bug or feature request?

Comment: I would say bug but you're welcome to correct it if you think otherwise.

Comment: I believe the same is true of the main help centre (im on mobile so can't check)